# Modal Logic: Possible Necessity implies Necessity in Godel's Ontological Proof?

Tags: logic, modal-logic

I am trying to understand Godel's Ontological proof, following [these notes](https://web.archive.org/web/20091222082410/http://www.stats.uwaterloo.ca/%7Ecgsmall/Godel.final.revision.PDF) by Christopher Small. As I have no background in logic, I am picking up what's necessary from modal logic as I read.

I am in particular stuck at the very last few steps of the proof, where one goes from the statement

> it is possibly necessary for a god-like individual to exist

to the statement

> it is necessary for a god-like individual to exist

In the notes of Small, he says this follows from the "contrapositive of Becker's postulate":
[image]

Here, $G$ is the predicate of being god-like, defined as the conjunction of all positive attributes.

In addition, (M6) refers to the modal axiom $$\Diamond p\to \Box \Diamond p$$ However, I am unable to see how the contrapositive of this implies the desired result.

There is a very helpful answer by @mjqxxxx for [this problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/287182) asked on Stackexchange, regarding how to understand Godel's proof. Unfortunately, this very last step, in this particular answer, does not have an explanation:

> it's possible that it's necessary for something godlike to exist; and so it is, in fact, necessary for something godlike to exist

And thus ends the proof of the final Theorem.

I believe it is possible that my elementary understanding of basic Modal logic is not allowing me to see something that is perhaps very obvious. I would greatly appreciate any help on this. Thank you.

Comment: To start, are you able to form the negation of $\Box\Diamond p$? Once you've done that, you should be able to construct the contrapositive of (M6). Since that holds for all propositions $p$, you can then substitute $(\exists y)(Gy)$ for $\lnot p$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the contrapositive of $\varphi\to \psi$ is $\lnot \psi\to \lnot \varphi$.

So the contrapositive of $\lozenge p\to \square\lozenge p$ is $\lnot \square \lozenge p\to \lnot \lozenge p$.

Now in modal logic, negation switches boxes and diamonds: $\lnot \square \varphi$ is equivalent to $\lozenge \lnot \varphi$ and $\lnot \lozenge \varphi$ is equivalent to $\square \lnot \varphi$. I suspect this is the key thing you were missing.

So our contrapositive is equivalent to $\lozenge \square \lnot p\to  \square \lnot p$.

Now substitute $\lnot (\exists y\, G(y))$ for $p$. The double negations cancel, and we get $\lozenge \square (\exists y\, G(y))\to  \square (\exists y\, G(y))$.

By the way, I had never heard $\lozenge p\to \square\lozenge p$ referred to as "Becker's postulate" before. It is more common to refer to this axiom as "**5**" (see [here](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-modal/#ModLog) or [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S5_(modal_logic)), for example). Because of this numerical convention, it's rather unfortunate that the notes you're reading refer to it as (M6).